# Direct uploading from user to another server in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, upload

I want the user to upload my his video file to dailymotion.
In my view I provide this input field...

```
[...]
<%= file_field 'file_path' %>
[...]
```

But this one causes my rails app to directly upload it to my rails app server.
I want the user to directly upload it to another server - dailymotion, in this case ( api works and doesn't matter here )

Can you guys help me or give me hints?

Answer (score 0):

S3SwfUpload allows user to upload a file to S3 directly, so you can save the cost of uploading process in your app server..

go to https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin

Comment: yeah it upload to S3, but I want to upload this file to dailymotion.
Am I able to upload it from S3 to dailymotion?